# Trailing Spaces

Tags: powershell, spaces, file-io

When I run the following command it results in having trailing spaces after each object. What is the best way for me to remove them?

Get-VMHost | select Name | out-file c:\temp\hosts.txt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you really need the table view for a single property? Remember that the table and list outputs are supposed to be read by humans, not piped into a file.

You can use

```
Get-VMHost | Select -Expand Name | Out-File hosts.txt
```

to just output the names.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Set-Content` (and/or `Add-Content`) to not have formatting artifacts.